( Google Play consol repeated content policy) how to upload same functionality app play console
Google Play console not allow apps that merely provide the same experience as other apps already on Google Play. Apps should provide value to users through the creation of unique content or services.
Like
enter image description here
But haw to this company upload multiple apps one console account
enter image description here
this company upload multiple same apps change icon and colour long time not problem this account how to possible. This company just change app name and icon and colour. But this company all app functionality is same weather related. Just app name change because different different country different different name use then app upload haw?
Examples this company all app violation violations Google repeated content policy
Creating multiple apps with highly similar functionality, content, and user experience. If these apps are each small in content volume, developers should consider creating a single app that aggregates all the content.
So I can ask how to upload multiple one console account this company
enter image description here
This company violation Google repeated  contain policy but not problem this account. This company upload similar multiple apps same account. I asked just how to possible because this company (see imge) all app functionality and wark is similar just a name and icon different.
